# tight lower bounds of parallel machine scheduling with gang scheduling constraint

Tags: optimization, approximation, scheduling

I am interested in tight bounds for the Parallel Machine scheduling problem with a [gang scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_scheduling) constraint.

In the [notation of Graham, Lawler, Lenstra and Rinnooy Kan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_job_scheduling), this might be called $Pm|\rm{gang}|C_{\rm{max}}$.

There are $m$ identical machines, and $n$ jobs.  Each job has both a processing time $p_j$, and a *gang size* $g_j$, which is the number of resources (machines) that it must be scheduled on simultaneously while it is running.  The optimization goal is to minimize the *makespan* (the time to completion of the last job).  For the purposes of this question I am concerned with the *off-line* version of the problem *without* preemption and *without* migration.

The need for the gang scheduling constraint for efficient execution of parallel programs with fine-grained synchronization was originally recognized by [Ousterhout in 1982](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eouster/cgi-bin/papers/coscheduling.pdf), and has been implemented in almost every parallel supercomputer resource manager that I'm aware of since the mid 1990s (and is currently implemented in Slurm, LSF, and PBS).

Two (weak) lower bounds on the makespan are $\max_{j} p_j$ and $\frac{\sum_j p_j g_j}{m}$.  But neither of these bounds are tight.  Consider for example the problem of scheduling 2 jobs onto a system with $m=2$.  The first job has $p_0=1, g_0=2$ and the second job has $p_1=2, g_1=1$.  So job 0 consumes all the resources in the entire system for 1 time unit, then job 1 consumes only half the machine, for 2 time units, and the minimum feasible schedule in this case has a makespan of 3, not 2.

An upper bound on the makespan is $\sum_j p_j$, which is tight in the case where all the jobs have $g_j > m/2$.

So how do I find tight lower bounds on the makespan of the optimal schedule?